# Unable to get Data in the Excel Sheet using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am unable to get data into the excel file that i am creating using Apache poi.
Jar used is 3.7

I am having this code.

```
    String classtitle=null;
    String query="select attsta.username,attsta.status,att.class_title,ind.fname,ind.lname,ind.gender from attendance att,attendancestatus attsta,individual ind where att.attendance_id='"+id+"' and att.attendance_id=attsta.attendance_id and ind.username=attsta.username and att.class_id='"+classid+"'";
    try
    {
        DBinfo obj=new DBinfo();
        Connection con=obj.getConnect();
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("lawix10");
        HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
        rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Username"));
        rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Class Title"));
        rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Name"));
        rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Gender"));
        int i = 1;
        while (rs.next())
        {
            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) i);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(rs.getString(1));
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(rs.getString(2));
            classtitle=rs.getString(3);
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(classtitle);
            System.out.print(classtitle);
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue(rs.getString(4));
            i++;
        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(classtitle+".xls");
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.flush();
        fileOut.close();

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+classtitle+".xls");
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        HSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
        System.out.println(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()+" "+sheet.getFirstRowNum()+" "+sheet.getLastRowNum());
```

I am getting the result of the last line of the code:`HSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
            System.out.println(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()+" "+sheet.getFirstRowNum()+" "+sheet.getLastRowNum());`
 as 9 0 8 which is the desired result. But the excel sheet which is downloaded by the browser is of 0 byte and no data.

Comment: Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292205(v=vs.71).aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334820/Using-Globalization-and-Localization-in-ASP-NET. This will point you in the right direction

Comment: What do yo mean by **raw code**? Does it show jsp, html, js, java code? Or does it show machine code (that you can't read)?

Comment: the whole jsp code and HTML code that i have written is coming on the web page.

Comment: Are you sure that tomcat is running? Do you know where tomcat is configured to write log files? Check /var/log/easy-tomcat7/catalina.out, /var/log/easy-tomcat7/catalina.err, /usr/local/apache/logs/mod_jk.log. Tomcat's log file will solve majority of your problems.